# FileNotFoundException Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: java, android, io

FileNotFoundException occur when capture the screen and save the screenshot into SDCard after power off the cellular phone, It seems that the server to flash the buffer into disk has disconnected during shutdown, but anyone can help me explain more detail? The output error message is:

> 02-24 14:03:28.180 27412 27412 D TakeScreenshotService:
>   @isFloatingBallVisible() ,visible = false
>
> 02-24 14:03:29.402 27412 10176 E SaveImageInBackgroundTask: error in
>   SaveImageInBackgroundData,
>   exception:java.io.**FileNotFoundException**:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20170224-140329.jpg:
>   open failed: ENOTCONN **(Transport endpoint is not connected)**
>
> 02-24 14:03:29.526 27412 27412 D TakeScreenshotService: onUnbind,
>   isMultiScrenshot:false intent:Intent {
>   cmp=com.android.systemui/.screenshot.TakeScreenshotService }

The corresponding codes are:

```
@Override
protected SaveImageInBackgroundData doInBackground(SaveImageInBackgroundData... params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground:");
    if (params.length != 1) return null;
    if (isCancelled()) {
        params[0].clearImage();
        params[0].clearContext();
        return null;
    }

    // By default, AsyncTask sets the worker thread to have background thread priority, so bump
    // it back up so that we save a little quicker.
    Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND);

    Context context = params[0].context;
    Bitmap image = params[0].image;
    Resources r = context.getResources();

    try {
        // Create screenshot directory if it doesn't exist
        mScreenshotDir.mkdirs();

        // media provider uses seconds for DATE_MODIFIED and DATE_ADDED, but milliseconds
        // for DATE_TAKEN
        long dateSeconds = mImageTime / 1000;

        // Save
        boolean compressRet = true;
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mImageFilePath);
        if(PhoneStatusBar.LEUI_ENABLE) {
            compressRet = image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        } else {
            compressRet = image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        if(!compressRet){
            //When storage is full screenshot image will compress failed, so we delete the file
            File f = new File(mImageFilePath);
            if(f.exists()){
                f.delete();
                Log.d(TAG,"screenshot " + mImageFilePath + " compress failed, so we delete it");
            }
            params[0].clearImage();
            params[0].result = 1;
        }else {
            // Save the screenshot to the MediaStore
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, mImageFilePath);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE, mImageFileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, mImageFileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN, mImageTime);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED, dateSeconds);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, dateSeconds);
            if(PhoneStatusBar.LEUI_ENABLE) {
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
            } else {
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
            }
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.WIDTH, mImageWidth);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.HEIGHT, mImageHeight);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE, new File(mImageFilePath).length());
            Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            // Create a share intent
            String subjectDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(mImageTime));
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            if(PhoneStatusBar.LEUI_ENABLE) {
                sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            } else {
                sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
            }
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mImageFileName);

            // Create a share action for the notification
            final PendingIntent callback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                    new Intent(context, GlobalScreenshot.TargetChosenReceiver.class)
                            .putExtra(GlobalScreenshot.CANCEL_ID, mNotificationId),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, null,
                    callback.getIntentSender());
            chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mNotificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_screenshot_share,
                    r.getString(com.android.internal.R.string.share),
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, chooserIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

            // Create a delete action for the notification
            final PendingIntent deleteAction = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,  0,
                    new Intent(context, GlobalScreenshot.DeleteScreenshotReceiver.class)
                            .putExtra(GlobalScreenshot.CANCEL_ID, mNotificationId)
                            .putExtra(GlobalScreenshot.SCREENSHOT_URI_ID, uri.toString()),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            mNotificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_screenshot_delete,
                    r.getString(com.android.internal.R.string.delete), deleteAction);

            params[0].imageUri = uri;
            params[0].image = null;
            params[0].result = 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // IOException/UnsupportedOperationException may be thrown if external storage is not
        // mounted
        Log.e(TAG, "error in SaveImageInBackgroundData, exception:" + e);
        params[0].clearImage();
        params[0].result = 1;
    }

    // Recycle the bitmap data
    if (image != null) {
        image.recycle();
    }

    return params[0];
}
```

Comment: `mScreenshotDir.mkdirs();`. Two coding errors. First you should only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist. Second: check the return value of mkdirs() as it might fail to create the directory and then returns false. Do not continue with the code then but stop. Having said this it is of course much better to care for the directory before you instantiate an async task.

Comment: Why are you saving to media store again after success full saving to disk?

Comment: save the screenshot file into SD Card and insert the relevant data into database which is used by Picture App.

Comment: if (!mScreenshotDir.exists()) {
 if(!mScreenshotDir.mkdirs()) {
  // failure
  return;
        }
}
So, the code should write as above? I agree that there is no need to create the directory every time when save the screenshot file, even through mkdirs() return false when the directory has existed or create failure according the API.

Comment: Yes that is code i had in mind. `I agree that there is no need to create the directory every time `. That is nonsense. One can create a directory only once.

Comment: So i guess all starts with a directory not beeing created.